# How to access resources in ASP.NET Views folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Resources in Views folder are CSS, Images used inside the View, now I know it is different then what it is meant for, we are already putting everything in Contents folder but I am looking for better way to manage it.

We have a very big MVC 4 and there are many areas and each area has many views. To maintain everything we created similar folder structure in contents folder to distribute CSS and images accordingly.

But the problem is, referencing each resource on view. It becomes difficult to keep track and here is the folder structure.

- Area

  - App

    - Controllers
    - Views

      - Projects

        - Search.cshtml
      - Users

        - Account.cshtml
- Content

  - common.less
  - App

    - app.less
    - some-button.png
    - projects.less
    - users.less

Now problem occurs when we have too many resources and cross referencing is difficult, as we make user interface changes, new views come in picture as project grows.

I would like to have resources as following format,

- Area

  - App

    - Controllers
    - Views

      - Projects

        - Search.cshtml
        - search.less
        - some-button.png
      - Users

        - Account.cshtml
        - account.less
        - some-button.png

How can I do easily?

Each of my controller is derived from a common AppController, in which we validate user authentication and roles. I have implemented CustomActionInvoker to find views as follow.

```
private string defaultViewName = "";

protected virtual object GetDefaultViewModel() {
    return null;
}

public virtual ActionResult DefaultView() {

    try
    {
        var view = this.View(defaultViewName);
        if (view == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound(defaultViewName + " View not found");
        }
        ViewBag.Title = defaultViewName;
    }
    catch
    {
        //Utils.Log(ex);
        //throw;
        return HttpNotFound(defaultViewName + " View not found");
    }            

    return View(defaultViewName, GetDefaultViewModel());
}

protected override IActionInvoker CreateActionInvoker()
{
    return new DefaultViewInvoker(base.CreateActionInvoker(), this);
}

internal class DefaultViewInvoker : ControllerActionInvoker {

    private IActionInvoker parent;
    private CastingWebController wc;

    internal DefaultViewInvoker(IActionInvoker parent, CastingWebController wc)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.wc = wc;
    }

    protected override ActionDescriptor FindAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, ControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, string actionName)
    {
        ActionDescriptor ad  = base.FindAction(controllerContext, controllerDescriptor, actionName);
        if (ad == null) {
            wc.defaultViewName = actionName;
            ad = base.FindAction(controllerContext, controllerDescriptor, "DefaultView");
        }
        return ad;
    }

}
```

This works well, it distributes the CSHTML file even if we have no action method on controller. However this does not work with CSS and images.

Example,

```
/App/Projects/Search
```

is easily processed and served by, we don't see raw CSHTML download anyway.

```
App/Views/Projects/Search.cshtml
```

I need little help in accessing

```
/App/Projects/Search.css
/App/Projects/some-button.png
```

at path

```
/App/Views/Projects/Search.css
/App/Views/Projects/some-button.png
```

As these are not CSHTML, view finder does not find them and also I need to serve them as static download, anything apart from cshtml,aspx and having a registered mime type.

And to add on it, we also have DisplayModes with Mobile and Tablet that makes it even difficult to manage resources.

Comment: Why are those resources in the Views folder? The Views folder is for... views.

Comment: @AntP of course I know, resources are CSS, images used inside the view.

Comment: Put them outside the views folder in "css" and "images" folders.

Comment: @AntP please read the question, we already have them in contents folder which is outside views anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit web.config in the ~/Views folder to allow access anything except .cshtml files by adding ***.cshtml** to path parameter

```
<system.webServer>
   <handlers>
     <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
     <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*.cshtml" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" 
         type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
   </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put anything in the Views folder that needs to be served to the browser.  That includes CSS (or less), images, javascript, whatever...

The reason for this is that MVC does not allow anything in the Views folders to be accessed by a web request directly for security reasons.  Views often contain code, which can reveal internal information about the server.  Sometimes people even do stupid things like putting usernames and passwords in their view code.

This is to prevent people from just typing this into their browsers:

```
http://yoursite/Views/Home/index.cshtml
```

in order to download the cshtml file.

Therefore, you simply cannot put anything in the Views folder, or any subfolder, that you wish for a browser to download.

If you look in your Views folder, you will see it has it's own web.config file.  In that file, you will find the following section, which adds an HttpHandler that blocks access to anything in the Views folder.  I would not suggest removing it, as this can make your code vulnerable.

```
<system.webServer>
   <handlers>
     <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
     <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" 
         type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
   </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why cannot UI dependencies still be kept in the Contents Folder and , make use of Bundling feature to package resource per view basis.